# Getting Inverted image from Django html view

Tags: python, django, numpy, matplotlib, mpld3

I am trying to make web-based snake&ladder game on `Django`, for which I am using `matplotlib` and `mpld3` to create and display my game data on web page.

I am able to get my image on the web page but it is inverted.

Where am I going wrong in this code?

my views.py file:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import mpld3 as mpld3
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def home(request):
    image =  mpimg.imread('platform3.png')
    figure = plt.figure(dpi=100)
    subplot = figure.add_subplot(111)
    subplot.set_xlim(0, 10)
    subplot.set_ylim(0, 10)
    subplot.imshow(image, extent=[0, 10, 0, 10])
    canvas = FigureCanvas(figure)
    response = django.http.HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    html_gen = 'graph.html'
    with open(html_gen, 'w') as f:
        f.write(mpld3.fig_to_html(figure))
        f.write("Hello")

    return render(request, html_gen)
```

should I provide the generated html_gen.html file too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place the `[0, 0]` in the lower left corner of the axes with:

```
subplot.imshow(image, extent=[0, 10, 0, 10], origin='lower')
```

Please have a look at the [`imshow()` docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)

**Update: How to check and set a default `image.origin` value**

1. Check:

   ```
   >>> import matplotlib as mpl
   >>> print(mpl.rcParams['image.origin'])
   upper
   ```
2. Set `lower` as a default value ([docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html)):

   ```
   $ echo "image.origin : lower" >> .config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc
   ```
3. Check again:

   ```
   >>> import matplotlib as mpl
   >>> print(mpl.rcParams['image.origin'])
   upper
   ```

Comment: This worked for me, but I have one question here, when I haven't mentioned origin, as default it took None right. So why does it got my image inverted? does it take some other value as origin?

Comment: By default (I'm using default packages from Ubuntu 16.04) `image.origin = 'upper'`. I've updated the answer with more info on a subject.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. I got it now. I am also using ubuntu 16.04 and used set lower as default as you mentioned.